# Android - Pairing two devices via QR code

Tags: android

I have two programs in Android.
1. Generate QR code
2. Scan QR code.
Now, i want to install two application in two different devices. In one device, QR code will be generated and the other will scan the generated QR code. After this i want to perform some function. But this functions can be done only after pairing the devices via QR code only.
Is it possible to do. If yes, then please help me with the source code.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "pairing the devices via QR code only" means.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Zbar.it is easy to integrate and use.Use this for reference https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner. let me know if you could integrate it